# Modal Pop up in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a modal in HTML code like as mentioned below.

```
<app-modal #modal1>
                <div class="app-modal-header">
                    header
                </div>
                <div class="app-modal-body">
                    Whatever content you like, form fields, anything
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="app-modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="modal1.hide()">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="modal2.show()">Show modal 2</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </app-modal>
```

I need to show this modal on click of a tab. How to show or hide this modal from typescript file inside a method.

Comment: Please show the what you've tried

Comment: I got this example online and as of now the example has a button in html on click of which the modal is shown like

Comment: <button type="button" (click)="modal1.show()">test</button>

Comment: And you don't want to do it from the template is that what you're asking?

Comment: But as per my requirement I have a method called addDetail(){} being called on adding a new tab and I want this modal to be popped up when I add a new tab. So, I need to make this dialog to be shown inside addDetail() method.

Comment: Use the view child decorator factory. It is a very unwieldy API that's really awkward to use but it is the only one available

Comment: You can also use the ngx-bootstrap library for modals which works well. http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

Comment: Thank you, but here also the hiding and showing of modal is on button click with which I will end up with the same issue again. Is there a better way to show and hide it with the existing approach.

Comment: You need to get a reference to the child component using the view child decorator Factory and use that to programmatically close and open it. That's going to be the case with pretty much any angular API

Comment: Is it possible for you to give one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
// boilerplate and ceremony
}) 
export default class {
  @ViewChild('modal1') modal1; // decorator argument matches #modal1 in template.

 addDetail() {
   this.modal1.show();
 }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that, could you expect this answer if that's the case?